# Returning a Redirect within then of an async function

Tags: reactjs

I developed a login service function with axios. In my login component I call the service as I click the login button.

All works fine with one exception: Page doesn't redirect to /home (route exists).

```
const loginRequest = async () => {
    return await loginService(username, password).then(
        (loginResponse) => {
            console.log('loginResponse', loginResponse);

            if(loginResponse.status == 'success') {
                setError('')
                return <Redirect to='/home'  />
            } else {
                setError('authenticate_failed')
            }
        }
    )
}
```

My routing is like this:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you share your routing code ?

Comment: @tolga share your code of routing and component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return Redirect under loginRequest, it's just the return value of onClick function of login button.
Not the render function.

You should use Router to redirect to login page.

```
this.props.history.push('/home')
```

Comment: I just found this answer and was about to write the same thing. Thank you.